# What is this rhythm game?

Tags: game-identification

What is the name of this game shown in VideoGameDunkey's [My Indie Game Publishing Company](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEt27Jgp8gs)?

[image: game image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This appears to be the game [Thumper](https://thumpergame.com/), comparing it to this video:

Around the 17 second mark appears to be the same scene as your image.